# Android appwidget does not start service when ran

Tags: android, service, android-appwidget

The problem I am having is that when I debug my widget, it changes the layout, but when I simply run it, it doesn't work. According to my debug messages, it sets the setOnClickPendingIntent but it does not start my service.

In short, my widget only works when debugging.

Here is my widget code:

```
    public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    public static String SWITCH_SCREEN1 = "1";
    public static String SWITCH_SCREEN2 = "2";

    public static final String ADD_NOTE = "addNote";
    public static final String MANAGE_REMINDERS = "manageReminders";
    public static String TAKE_PICTURE = "takePicture";


    private static int LAYOUTID = R.layout.widget_screen1;

    /**
     * This method is called when a widget is added to the home screen.
     * It sets the listeners on the items and updates the screen with info from the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {
        super.onEnabled(context);
        setListeners(context);
        updateScreenFromDatabase(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class)));
    }


    /**
     * This method is called to update the widget. The Widget is called when the timeout set in widget.xml occurs.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        updateScreenFromDatabase(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    }

    /**
     * This method fetches the data from the database and puts it in the 2 text elements on the screen
     * @param context
     * @param appWidgetManager
     * @param appWidgetIds
     */
    private static void updateScreenFromDatabase(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {
        if(LAYOUTID == R.layout.widget_screen1){
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), LAYOUTID);
            for(int i = 0 ; i < appWidgetIds.length ; i++){
                String currentLesson = "No current lesson";
                String nextLesson = "No next lesson";
                LessonHour[] hours = Database.getInstance(context).getCurrentAndNextLessonHour();
                if(hours[0] != null){
                    currentLesson = hours[0].getStart().get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + Utils.adjustMinutes(hours[0].getStart().get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE)) + " " + hours[0] .getLesson().getSummary();
                }
                if(hours[1] != null){
                    nextLesson = hours[1].getStart().get(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" +  Utils.adjustMinutes(hours[1].getStart().get(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE)) + " " + hours[1] .getLesson().getSummary();
                }
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_widget_lesson1, currentLesson);
                views.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_widget_lesson2, nextLesson);

                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), views);  
            }
        }

    }



    /**
     * This method is called when the screen of the widget should change.
     * The action tells the method to which screen it should change. 
     * @param context
     * @param action: the screen the method should switch to. Either WIDGET_SCREEN1 or WIDGET_SCREEN2
     */
    public static void buildUpdate(Context context, String action){
        RemoteViews views;
        if(action.equals(SWITCH_SCREEN1)){
            views =  new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_screen1);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), views);
            LAYOUTID = R.layout.widget_screen1;
            updateScreenFromDatabase(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class)));
        }
        else if(action.equals(SWITCH_SCREEN2)){
            views =  new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_screen2);
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), views);
            LAYOUTID = R.layout.widget_screen2;
        }
        setListeners(context);
    }
    /**
     * This methods sets the onclick listeners for the elements displayed on the screen
     * @param context
     */
    private static void setListeners(Context context){
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds = manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class));

        for (int i = 0 ; i < appWidgetIds.length; i++){

            if(LAYOUTID == R.layout.widget_screen1){
                Log.e("khlrooster", "setting listeners on widget screen 1");
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), LAYOUTID);

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SwitchWidgetScreenService.class);
                intent.setAction(SWITCH_SCREEN2);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("uri::" + Math.random()));
                Log.e("khlrooster", "action of listener for screen 1: " + intent.getAction());
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_switchDown, pi);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_widget_notification, pi);

                manager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), views);
                Log.e("khlrooster", "listeners set on widget screen 1");
            }

            else if(LAYOUTID == R.layout.widget_screen2){
                Log.e("khlrooster", "setting listeners on widget screen 2");
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), LAYOUTID);
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, SwitchWidgetScreenService.class);
                intent2.setAction(SWITCH_SCREEN1);              
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent2, 0);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_switchUp, pendingIntent);

                intent2 = new Intent(context, LessonDetail.class);
                intent2.setAction(ADD_NOTE);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_notes, pendingIntent);

                intent2= new Intent(context, LessonDetail.class);
                intent2.setAction(TAKE_PICTURE);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent2, 0);
                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imgbtn_photo, pendingIntent);                

                manager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), views);
                Log.e("khlrooster", "listeners set on widget screen 2");
            }

        }
    }


}
```

and here is my service responding to my Intents:

```
public class SwitchWidgetScreenService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.e("khlrooster", "Created the SwitchWidgetScreenService");
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //super.onStart(intent, startId);
    Log.e("khlrooster", "started the SwitchWidgetScreenService");
    handleEvent(intent);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    handleEvent(intent);
    Log.e("khlrooster", "started the SwitchWidgetScreenService");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

private void handleEvent(Intent intent) {
    Log.e("khlrooster", "it works, the screen changes to: " + intent.getAction());
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Widget.SWITCH_SCREEN1)){
        Widget.buildUpdate(this, Widget.SWITCH_SCREEN1);
    }else if(intent.getAction().equals(Widget.SWITCH_SCREEN2)){
        Widget.buildUpdate(this, Widget.SWITCH_SCREEN2);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem, I called setListeners once more after getting the data from the DB.